# How to XML serialize an Unknown type?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

In My application I am doing XML serialization, the problem is that if we want to serialize a type, there should be a `[Serializable]` attribute on that class, in my case I am getting unknown object to serialize How can I do that?

for example I want to serialize this :

```
 public class UnKnownType
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DateTime DOB
    {
        get;
        set;

    }
    public bool IsPrimary
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I get this error on serializing

at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o)
   at ConsoleApplication4.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\New Adventures\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\Program.cs:line 29

Comment: can you post some relevant code ?

Comment: Worst case scenario you can cast your `UnknownObject` to `Object`, and then Serialize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML serialization doesn't require the SerializableAttribute.
You must be aware however, that only properties that have public getters and setters are serialized.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you have a class such as

```
class MyClass
{
    IMyInterface Something{get; set;}
}
```

Then you can tell XmlSerializer the type of `IMyInterface` at the time of instantiating:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass), new Type[] {typeof(MyImplementation)}
```

Where `MyImplementation` implements `IMyInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

Ttry to use `XamlWriter.Save(unknownObject)`. It's very smart serializer :-)